# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] [Nodejs-Express]

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, jwt

I'm facing this weird issue in NodeJS when using with Express and Mysql. Basically, I get an error saying "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" even though I don't send more than one header.

I've read other posts and tried them out as well, and none of them worked.

```
router.post("/:id/:token", async (req, res) => {

    jwt.verify(req.params.token, config.secret , function(err, decoded) {
        if(err)  { 
                 res.status(400).send(err);
                  return; }
        else { res.status(200).send(decoded);
               return; }
    })}
```

console results:

[image]

Comment: All headers must be sent BEFORE any other output is sent to the browser. You must have done something to start sending something to the browser, it could even be as simnple as a single space.

Comment: I didn't get well your answer

Comment: something in your code is sending HTML or something to the browser BEFORE you run this code that is sending a header. That is not allowed, headers MUST be sent before any other data to the browser

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70018504/edit) to show there rest of your application, including any middleware. It's possible that there's a middleware or some other handler that attempts to also send a response.

Comment: I solved it @RiggsFolly is right I have sent header before any other data to the browser Thank you all

Comment: @cbr Thank you I solve it